# Iphone gathering information from a Remote sqlite

Tags: iphone

I need to write an application which gathers information from an Sqlite db which is located on a remote server, and not on the iphone physically.

Can you point me on some examples, documentations on how to figure out this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is inherently a local database system. It is not directly accessible through the network. As such, you're going to have to implement a frontend to your remote sqlite database with - say - PHP to provide the data in a form (like XML or JSON) you can process on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you are going to want some sort of service to allow you to exchange information from your db to the phone. You  can use NSURLRequest/NSURLMutableRequest and NSURLConnection to use  your service over http to retrieve data.

Comment: Do you have some example code? For example a simple server side code (e.g. in php) and the client code for IPHONE?
I mean just to understand....